# What's the process to get an Indonesian tourist visa for a US citizen?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, thailand, bangkok, indonesia

I'm in Bangkok at the moment, but according to the stamp in my passport, I'm gonna have to skip soon.

I'm thinking I'd like to visit Indonesia [to check out the lifestyle entrepreneur scene](http://blog.thefetch.com/2014/01/23/work-life-haven-why-entrepreneurs-and-digital-nomads-are-settling-in-bali/), but it appears that [I will need a visa to do so](http://indonesia.visahq.com/requirements/United_States/resident-Thailand/).

What's the process to get an Indonesian tourist visa for a US citizen?  What do I need to bring with me, and what's the turnaround time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A tourist visa for US citizens can obtained upon arrival for 25 USD, preferably cash, exact change.

After you deplane you first stop will be immigration. Before immigration there will be some well signed, official, booths for obtaining visa on arrival (VOA). There will be a fee of 25USD (this it not a bribe or anything of that nature, but a legitimate fee). It's payable by cash or credit card. I would recommend having enough cash on hand in case the credit card system is not operational/available. There are also ATMs nearby and you **may** be able to pay in Indonesian Ruppiah, which is what the ATMs will probably dispense. 1 USD ~= 10,000 IDR.

Once you have paid the visa fee they will place your visa in your passport. From there it is a straight shot through immigration **in a line marked for people who did VOA**. No need to stand in the line for non-VOA visa people. Someone will check your passport to make sure there's a visa in there. Then on to baggage.

Some of these details may apply specifically to Soekarno-Hatta International Airport (CGK) but the principles should apply throughout Indonesia.

Comment: make that ONLY cash. The entry and exit fee payment booths do not accept credit cards, checks, or ATM cards. They're purely cash only. Furthermore, the ones for entry visa accept foreign currency only, the internal ones seem to accept local currency only (but might be different at international airports, I was told to not even try dollars or Euros). It also greatly helps to have exact change, speeds things up and the attendant might not have or be in the mood to count out the change to give you (especially as any change would always be in local currency, not dollars or Euros).

Comment: And no, other airports (except maybe at Bali) are unlikely to have any foreign currency option, or ATMs or credit card terminals. It's just a guy standing somewhere with a stack of preprinted receipts and a wallet most of the time.

Comment: The immigration section of CGK accepts credit cards.

Comment: when I was there the on arrival visa desk had a sign "cash only" with a list of accepted currencies. Maybe was just that desk or there was a technical problem.

Comment: 6 months ago the credit card system was 'down' when I went through (no issue, had the cash).  Two weeks  ago nothing indicated the system was down. Anything other than a cash is a risk though.  My comments apply only to CGK.

Answer (score 4):

You may get visa when you'll arrive in Indonesia http://www.embassyofindonesia.org/consular/voa.htm